# Responsive Design and Joomla Component

Tags: html, css, joomla, responsive-design

I'm building a form for my joomla website and I have a problem.

This div show a basic input :

```
<div class="ccms_form_element cfdiv_text" id="input_text_11_container_div" style="">
        <label>Nom*</label>
        <input maxlength="150" size="30" class="" title="" type="text" value="" name="input_text_1" />
        <div class="clear"></div><div id="error-message-input_text_1"></div>
    </div>
```

And in my responsive design I just want to modify the size of the input, so manually if a put `size=10`, the box become littler. But how do I do with responsive ?

I tried this :

```
@media screen and (max-width:460px) {
    input[type="text"] {
        width:50%;    
    }
    .cfdiv_text, .ccms_form_element, .cfdiv_datetime {
        width:50%;

      }
}
```

This doesn't work ..

Thanks for your help guys :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you will define this Css code in bottom of your major code for Css.

and media query template is :

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 460px) {
     /* Styles */
}
```

Comment: No there is 3 differents template, I don't want this one, I need to check the size of window not only the screen ;) Still this is not an answer

Comment: If possible you uploaded your project for i that test your project.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason it didn't work the first time is because css was overriden by other css so I just add !important at the end of the property line and now it works fine :) :

```
input[type="text"], input[type="file"] {
    width: 60% !important;
  }
```